# Populate tmp table with the data returned from two queries

Tags: mysql, sql, temp-tables

I'm trying to create a temporary table filled with the returned data from two queries. Here is what I tried

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp AS (
 SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `v1` = 1
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `v2` = 1
)
select * from tmp;
```

Here is what I get as result

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
```

Comment: `WHERE 1 IN (v1,v2)` OR `WHERE v1 = 1 OR v2 = 1`?

Comment: Great! This WHERE 1 IN (v1,v2) is what I was looking for

Comment: You're welcome. Though it only solves this case (hence a comment instead of an answer). There may be cases where a union is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp AS 
 SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `v1` = 1
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `v2` = 1
;
select * from tmp;
```

Please refer to http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1302a7/1 for demonstration

Comment: What you suggest doesn't give an error but the tmp table is empty

Comment: @moemoe *but the tmp table is empty* it's because most likely your `tmp` table already exists. Drop it first and then try again. It should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Please try.  This is just the syntax. Please update your query accordingly.

```
create temporary table tmp
select * from
 (
   (select * from users)
     UNION
   (select * from users)
 ) bt;

 SELECT * FROM tmp;
```